# why is assert capselled in an if checking the actual assertion in the IEEE lib?

Tags: vhdl

While implementing a `function "or"` for a self defined array type, I decided to have a look at the implementation of `"or"` for `std_logic_vector`.
There I stumbled over code like this:

(extract, I don't know if there is such a thing as copytright for this, since each vendor can have his own implementation).

```
funciton "or" (Left, Right: std_logic_vector) is
    ...
begin
    if Left'LENGTH /= Right'LENGTH then
        assert FALSE report
        "ErrorDifferentLengthVectors" severity failure;
    else
        ...
    end if;
end "or";
```

where is the advantage of `this over using the`condition`-part of the`report statement as follows? Won't the assertion cancel further compilation anyways or is there need to put the following code in an else branch?

```
funciton "or" (Left, Right: std_logic_vector) is
    ...
begin
    assert Left'LENGTH = Right'LENGTH report
    "ErrorDifferentLengthVectors" severity failure;

    ...

end "or";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a coding style thing. If you do it with `assert` you have to negate the condition. If you write multiple, exlusive `elsifs` you always have to invert that first condition in your head to work out which cases you already have covered in the if statement. At least that's why I do it in a simmilar fasion, but I ommit the assert all together and only use `report ... severity failure;`.

An example would be the following snippets:
A:

```
  signal value : natural := 0;

begin  -- architecture beh

  -- purpose: none
  do_something : process (all) is
  begin  -- process to_something
    if rst = '0' then                   -- asynchronous reset (active low)
      value <= 0,
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then         -- rising clock edge
        assert value >= 10 and value <= 99  report "Value out of range." severity failure;
        if value < 15 then
          do something;
        elsif value > 20 and value < 50 then
          do some other thing;
        else
          do yet another thing;
        end if;
      end if;
  end process do_something;
```

B:

```
   signal value : natural := 0;

begin  -- architecture beh

  -- purpose: none
  do_something : process (all) is
  begin  -- process to_something
    if rst = '0' then                   -- asynchronous reset (active low)
      value <= 0,
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then         -- rising clock edge
        if value < 10 or value > 99 then
          report "Value out of range." severity failure;
        elsif value < 15 then
          do something;
        elsif value > 20 and value < 50 then
          do some other thing;
        else
          do yet another thing;
        end if;
      end if;
  end process do_something;
```

It is harder to understand when which condition of Snipped A comes into play than it is in snipped B, especially the `else` clauses, and there is only one numeric value being checked in this example.

Comment: I still find it unnatural, since they don't have different exclusive assertions. I needed to read your awnser twice to notice that there are cases where **multiple exclusive `assertion`**s make sense and introduce the appeal of `if` capsuling this. Adding an example and pointing this out could turn your awnser from an accepted one into a great one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will edit it later. The main gist ist that I don't like the inverted condition for readability and maintenance, especially if it's mixed with non-inverted conditions like if/elsif statements.

Comment: If you write code like this yourself, you should write `report "message" severity error` instead of `assert false report ...`.

Comment: see the examples in my Answer, I do omit the `assert false` part. I have however seen a lot of legacy vhdl where `assert false ...` is used, could it be that prior to some version, the `assert` could not be omited?